# psr-4 changes to working examples do not work

Tags: psr-4

I have to achieve that all sources are inclueded like this

`$instance = new \d1\d2\d3\app\MyClass();`

Where d1\d2\d3\ points to the root directory.

I have read the basics on 
https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4 
and on 
http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/. 
The example on https://laracasts.com/lessons/psr-4-autoloading also works for me.

My problem is: a soon as I change the code below a little bit towards to my needs the class is not found any more. (Yes I issue the command `composer update` after the changes in composer.json. And yes I updated the composer using self-update).

**So this works:**

*composer.json*

`"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {

        "Laracasts\\": "app/Laracasts"
    }
}`

*index.php*

`require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
// According to https://laracasts.com/lessons/psr-4-autoloading
$test = new \Laracasts\Repositories\BlogRepository();
$test->hello();`

**But this does'nt:**

*composer.json*

`"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {

        "d1\\": "app/Laracasts"
    }
}`

*index.php*

`require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
// According to https://laracasts.com/lessons/psr-4-autoloading
$test = new \d1\Repositories\BlogRepository();
$test->hello();`

What am I doing wrong?

I am using php 5.3.28 with IIS 8.

Comment: The path to the class BlogRepository is app\Laracasts\Repositories\BlogRepository.php

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

The problem was that Prefix used in composer.json ('d1' in this case) must also be used as the Namespace-Prefix in the class to be included. And this was not the case while I posted the previous post.

For the non-working example above to work the files must look like this in case of 'd1':

**app\Laracasts\Repositories\BlogRepository.php**

`namespace d1\Repositories;
    class BlogRepository
    {
        public function hello(){
        echo 'hello from a non-root dir!';
        }
    }`

**index.php**

`require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
$test = new \d1\Repositories\BlogRepository();
$test->hello();`

**composer.json**

`{
    "autoload": {
         "psr-4": {
            "d1\\": "app/Laracasts"
         }
     }
}`

The achieve that d1\d2\d3\ points to the root directory, we have to adjust the prefix in all 3 files mentioned above and move the file with the class to the root directory. Then we have adjust the composer.json like this
`"d1\\d2\\d3\\": ""`